# Making the client app do 2 HTTP GET requests to mimic an unsupported one

Tags: web-services, http, get, webserver

Is it okay to make a client app do 2 HTTP GET requests to mimic an unsupported one?  I'm building a web service that handles events and venues, but the queries could either be for:

Venue1 AND Venue2 or Venue1 OR Venue2

I was thinking a way to allow for both is to have the web service allow for Venue1 OR Venue2 and then force the client app to do a GET request on each venue and then do the Venue1 AND Venue2 operation on the client end.

So the service only offers Venue1 OR Venue2, but the client will have to GET Venue1 and Venue2 independently and perform an AND operation on their end.

Is there a standard way of doing this?